# Как по имеющимся координатам начала и конца двух линий узнать пересекаются ли они? Аналог Line2D.intersectsLine на Android

Tags: java, android, геометрия

**Дано:**

Координаты 4 (A, B, C, D) точек на плоскости (`int x`, `int y`).

**Задача:**

Узнать пересекутся ли линии, A-B и C-D.

**Проблема:**

Как я понял из [гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5979033/3212712), то в java есть класс Line2D, а у него метод `intersectsLine(Line2D line)` возвращающий то, что надо. Но в андроиде нема пакета `java.awt.geom`. Нашёл на gitHub [порт](https://github.com/pokowaka/android-geom) библиотеки сей, но он древний и почти без звёзд и заброшен.

**Вопрос:**

Так таки есть ли готовые решения сей задачи или надо вспоминать геометрию и собирать велосипед?

Comment: http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/geometry-games/intersection-lines.html как вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам код из `java.awt.geom.Line2D.linesIntersect`, он ссылается только на один метод `java.awt.geom.Line2D.relativeCCW`

```
public static boolean linesIntersect(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, 
                                     double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) {

    boolean r1 = relativeCCW(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) * 
                 relativeCCW(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4) <= 0;

    boolean r2 = relativeCCW(x3, y3, x4, y4, x1, y1) * 
                 relativeCCW(x3, y3, x4, y4, x2, y2) <= 0;
    return r1 && r2;
}


public static int relativeCCW(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
                              double px, double py) {
    x2 -= x1;
    y2 -= y1;
    px -= x1;
    py -= y1;
    double ccw = px * y2 - py * x2;
    if (ccw == 0.0) {
        ccw = px * x2 + py * y2;
        if (ccw > 0.0) {
            px -= x2;
            py -= y2;
            ccw = px * x2 + py * y2;
            if (ccw < 0.0) {
                ccw = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
    return (ccw < 0.0) ? -1 : ((ccw > 0.0) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Хм... Потестил - вроде работает... Неужто всё было так просто? =) Но почему ж тогда из андроида это вырезали?.. 0_о

Comment: Чисто идеологически awt нечего делать в android вот и вырезали

Answer (score 1):

Если ничего не напутал, то

```
boolean intersection(double x1, double y1, ... double x4, double y4){
    Double x=null;
    double y;
    Double a,a1=null,a2=null;
    Double b,b1=null,b2=null;
    if(x1==x2){
        if(x3==x4) return false;
        x=x1;
    }else{
        a1=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
        b1=y1-a1*x1;
    }

    if(x3==x4){
        x=x3;
    }else{
        a2=(y3-y4)/(x3-x4);
        b2=y3-a2*x3;
    }

    if(x==null){
        x=(b2-b1)/(a1-a2);
    }
    if(x==x1){
        a=a2;
        b=b2;
    }else{
        a=a1;
        b=b1;
    }
    if(x>Math.max(x1,x2)||x>Math.max(x3,x4)||x<Math.min(x1,x2)||x<Math.min(x3,x4)) return false;
    y=a*x+b;

    return y>=Math.min(y1,y2)&&y<=Math.max(y1,y2)&&y>=Math.min(y3,y4)&&y<=Math.max(y3,y4);
}
```

Comment: В этом месте пишет (`if(x==null){
            x=(b2-b1)/(a1-a2);
        }` что все переменные могут быть неинициализированы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не могут

Comment: ну, у меня не компилируется... И ругается, что x (double) не может быть null, ибо оно примитивное https://www.dropbox.com/s/mivnmweuywdsx2x/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202016-06-12%2017.45.23.png?dl=0

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а, ну да. Надо просто поменять на Double для x. Поправил.

Comment: Всё равно не компилируется... https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zjcfuycv7dmf7y/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202016-06-12%2018.32.33.png?dl=0

Comment: @ЮрийСПб поправил. Но idea все равно ругается на a1,a2,b1,b2 - но это уже глюки анализатора. Есть повод завести проблему в их багтреккере

Comment: Потестил (1000 прогонов со случайными x-y для 4 точек) и в некоторых случаях не срабатывает. Выдаёт false в случае пересечения (Пример - 444/974, 867/445,  698/713, 496/694). При этом код из `java.awt.geom.Line2D.linesIntersect` эти случаи правильно отрабатывает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а на каких?

Comment: Я в предыдущем сообщении, в примере привёл координаты 4 точек. Если соединить 1 и 2, то они пересекутся с отрезком 3-4, но ваш код выдаёт false;

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня вот только что ответило, что пересекутся. if(inter(444,974, 867,445, 698,713, 496,694))Log.d("INTERSECT","YES");
else Log.d("INTERSECT","NO"); //D/INTERSECT: YES

Comment: Хм... У меня выводит `false`... Я поменял, вроде, только вот это `double a,a1=0,a2=0; double b,b1=0,b2=0;`. Т.е. инициализировал нулями, чтоб скомпилировалось. Ну и аргументы метода у меня `int`, но, кажется, это не должно роли играть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41089/discussion-between-rjhdby-and-).